# What is happening in this step in the derivation of a physics equation. ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading about the equation for Rayleigh scattering and trying to follow the derivation. I can follow along until this part:

[image]

I don't follow how it goes from equation 1 to equation 2. Is it just having to solve an ODE? I haven't thought about ODEs for a while so I will have to go back and revisit how this is done.

Or is it a very simple step that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Are there missing squares in the difference $\omega_0 - \omega$?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes you're right. I will change the question now. Thank you.

Comment: This is just the standard solution for a forced undamped oscillator. Search it up to see a derivation.

Comment: The straightest approach is to 'guess' a particular solution of the form $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)$, and infer $A$ by inspection.